# Gorilla mux, count all incoming requets

Tags: go, chaining, mux

I have a server using gorilla mux. Now I have two handlers like this:

```
api.HandleFunc("/foo", logHandler(mypackage.fooHandler)).Methods("GET")
api.HandleFunc("/bar", logHandler(mypackage.barHandler)).Methods("GET")
```

Now I would like to create a generic method (`logHandler`) which counts the requests. Now I have something like this:

```
func logHandler(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // what to do here???
  }
}
```

I can get all my necessary information from the request (r) in the logHandler function, but what do I need to return? How do I get this to work?

Comment: Don't need to return anything since `http.HandlerFunc` is defined as having no return argument, just make sure you call the passed in handler func `fn` inside the returned `http.HandlerFunc`. E.g. `fn(w, r)`. https://play.golang.org/p/ugqZp1vBz5B

Comment: Just count your requests there.

Comment: Consider using [`r.Use()`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router.Use) to install middleware.

Comment: Just in case you would like to use prometheus: https://violetear.org/post/prometheus/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
var count = 0
func logHandler(fn http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        atomic.AddInt32(&count, 1)
        log.Println(count)
        fn(w, r)
    }
}
```

<del>and just a heads up, I am not sure if `count` variable is thread safe or not. if not you might want to use `channels` to send out a signal to increment the counter</del>

I have Updated the answer to avoid race conditions. using atomic as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yes, this races against other handlers. Use a mutex to protect count, or something along the lines of `atomic.AddInt32(&count, 1)`.